# Does Gear VR with Samsung s7 edge support user position tracking?

Tags: virtual-reality, gear-vr, samsung-edge

I want to find user movement walking and tracking position and move camera accordingly in virtual reality app , not head movements like rotation , etc. So I am wondering whether this combination Gear VR with Samsung S7 edge will support my requirement or not.
Any suggestion will be appreciated , thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GearVR is not meant to be a 6-DoF device, which is what you are asking (3 Degrees of Freedom means tracking of rotation, 6 Degrees of Freedom means rotation + position).

It is possible to achieve 6-DoF tracking with a Samsung Galaxy by using ARCore. A good starting point would be [this GitHub project](https://github.com/ChristophGeske/ARCoreInsideOutTrackingGearVr).

However, the results will most likely not meet your expectations in terms of usability. If you intend to use the original GearVR goggles, you'll notice that the camera is covered, so that would be a problem as well.

If you really want quality mobile 6-DoF VR (read: goggles, not a smartphone in your hands), you should look out for Vive Focus or Oculus Quest as a device.